# How to join 2 tables with select and count in a single query

Tags: php, mysql, string, count, inner-join

I am new at stackoverflow and I probably have very simple question for most of you here :)

Dont have lots of knowledge of php and mysql and thats why I decided to ask for help.

I have 2 tables:

First table called **tags** with **id** and **name** in it.

Second table is called **products** and my focus is on **description**.

And this is what I want to accomplish:

Select **name** from **tags** table, pass it into **products** table, find how many products contain **name** inside **products** table **description** and get **count**. Also show only result with count bigger then 0, hide **name** with 0 value. And sort results by count, higher to lower number.

Final result example:

name1 (15), name2 (9), name3 (5) etc.

name4 (0) - hidden

Hope someone understand me what I wrote here omg :)

I am editing ready made script and have very little knowledge of php and mysql so dont be harsh on me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join and aggregate:

```
select t.name, count(*) cnt
from tags t
inner join products p on p.description like concat('%', p.name, '%')
group by t.id, t.name
```

I added the `id` of the tag in the `group by` clause, in case there are duplicate tag `name`s - if there aren't, this won't hurt either.

Comment: Thank you very much, you show me the right path :)I needed to change concat('%', p.name, '%')

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, you showed me the right path :) I needed to change concat('%', p.name, '%') into concat('%', t.name, '%') because results not worked very well. Added some WHERE, WHERE is part of default search and added ORDER BY cnt DESC at the end and everything works perfectly :D You helped me a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

try 1 - this will find '%' tags.name '%'

```
SELECT count(name) as c, MIN(name) as n FROM tags 
LEFT JOIN products 
ON products.description LIKE CONCAT( '%', tags.name, '%' ) 
GROUP BY tags.name 
ORDER BY COUNT(name) DESC
```

try 2 - add WHERE tags.id <> 0

```
SELECT count(name) as c, MIN(name) as n FROM tags 
LEFT JOIN products 
ON products.description LIKE CONCAT( '%', tags.name, '%' ) 
WHERE tags.id <> 0
GROUP BY tags.name 
ORDER BY COUNT(name) DESC
```

try 3 - you may add a column in tags for 'hide' if you need multiple hide tags.

```
SELECT count(name) as c, MIN(name) as n FROM tags 
LEFT JOIN products 
ON products.description LIKE CONCAT( '%', tags.name, '%' ) 
WHERE tags.hide = 0
GROUP BY tags.name 
ORDER BY COUNT(name) DESC
```